# Installation using Wubi froze after a network router reboot

Tags: installation, wubi

I have used Wubi installer to install Ubuntu in Windows. Its download progress stopped in middle due to a network router reboot. My Internet connection is fine now  but the download progress stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to reboot your router during Installation process. You have to uninstall wubi and reinstall again.